# Kafka schema registry 409s on google.protobuf.struct.proto

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a Kafka Streams application using Protobuf for message schemas. For now the application itself is just piping from one topic to another.
I'm running Kafka locally using the [Confluent platform all-in-one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one) docker-compose file.

One of my schemas (`foo.proto`) uses a `Struct` field, so prior to starting my app I have registered both `foo.proto` and [`struct.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) on the schema registry.

When I start my app the protobuf serializer runs a method called `resolveDependencies`, leading it to re-register `subtruct.proto`. The (local) schema registry returns a 409 with message:

```
Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema
```

The code that originally registers `struct.proto` and the app are both using version `3.12` of the `protobuf-java` library.
Looking at the docker logs for the registry, they give me a bit more detail with the following message:

```
Found incompatible change: Difference{fullPath='#/ListValue/1', type=FIELD_NAMED_TYPE_CHANGED}
```

Looking at that particular field the already registered schema has the following definition

```
message ListValue {
  repeated Value values = 1;
}
```

and the schema my application is trying to register has

```
message ListValue {
  repeated .google.protobuf.Value values = 1;
}
```

**My questions**

1. Why is the kafka-streams application trying to re-register dependencies?
2. When registering that dependency, why does the kafka-streams app end up with that namespaced type name?
3. Why does the schema registry consider those fields as having different types? Can it not understand the namespaced references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was just to not pre-register the schemas, and instead start from a clean schema registry. The kafka-streams app auto-registered the relevant schemas.

I am guessing that the way I registered the original schema wasn't quite correct.